# How to Create 4 Grid Blocks in bootstarp with full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How could I possibly create four grid blocks with height and width in percentage so it could automatically resize on mobile, below is the image of what i am talking about.

I mean - 4 grid blocks , one big one at the left , and one at the right top, with the remaining two juts below the second grid block, trust me this is how best i can explain this, i would so much love and appreciate your Help.

```html
<div class="the-home-big-grid">
  <div class="the-real-big-grid">
    <div class="first-big-guy">
      <img src="assets/img/7.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
      <div class="biggrid-overlay">
        <div class="before-big-grid-overlay-content">
        </div>
        <p class="the-big-grid-overlay-cat">
          Web Designing
        </p>
        <h2 class="biggrid-the-featured-title">
    <a href="#">The Diffrent typs of Desk there is</a>
     </h2>
        <div class="the-big-grid-featred-post-data">
          <img src="assets/img/avatar2.jpg" class="the-auth-post-image-featured" />By <a href="#">Neon Emmanuel</a>  <span class="the-featured-post-date"> <i class="fa fa-clock-o the-featured "></i>3rd Dec 2016</span> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="secound-big-guy">
    <img src="assets/img/2.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
    <div class="secound-biggrid-overlay">
      <div class="before-secound-grid-overlay-content">
      </div>
      <p class="the-secound-grid-overlay-cat">
        Web Designing
      </p>
      <h2 class="secound-the-featured-title">
    <a href="#">The Diffrent typs of Desk there is</a>
    </h2>
      <div class="the-secound-grid-featred-post-data">
        <img src="assets/img/avatar2.jpg" class="the-auth-post-image-featured" />By <a href="#">Neon Emmanuel</a>  <span class="the-featured-post-date"> <i class="fa fa-clock-o the-featured "></i>3rd Dec 2016</span> 
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="third-big-guy">
    <img src="assets/img/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
    <div class="third-biggrid-overlay">
      <div class="before-third-grid-overlay-content">
      </div>
      <p class="the-third-grid-overlay-cat">
        Web Designing
      </p>
      <h2 class="third-the-featured-title">
    <a href="#">The Diffrent typs of Desk there is</a>
    </h2>
      <div class="the-third-grid-featred-post-data">
        <img src="assets/img/avatar2.jpg" class="the-auth-post-image-featured" />By <a href="#">Neon Emmanuel</a>  <span class="the-featured-post-date"> <i class="fa fa-clock-o the-featured "></i>3rd Dec 2016</span> 
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Image 
[Below is the image of what i meain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPgXw.jpg)

Comment: You're going to get voted down into oblivion because this isn't how SO works. You need to try solving this yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

Here's Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/JlOEZaBkNs

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">A
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">C</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">D</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tanks bro , this was exactly what i needed